# how to print stack trace only once instead of continuously printing it to console?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have a reader module written in Java that checks whether a reader is connected to the system and if yes it scans any tags present in its vicinity.

If the reader is not connected, the program continuously throws following exception stack trace:

```
Exception de.feig.FedmException: 
Error -111 - Error in Module FEDM: No port handle set
(in Function: FedmIscReader_SendProtocol(0xB0), Line: 3362)
native Library Version: 04.07.0
```

Here is the code that is generating the above exception:

```
try {
        fedm = new FedmIscReader();
    }
catch (de.feig.FedmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
catch(java.lang.Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

The problem here is that I'm writing the output of this program into a nohup file on Ubuntu system and this file size grows to a large extent since the above exception is written continuously to this file. 
I want this exception to be written to nohup only once and continue detecting for any reader connections. How do I achieve this? 
Any suggestion or solution for this is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Keep a boolean flag that determines whether the stacktrace has already been written?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find any public documentation about the de.feig library, but if the stack trace is written out continuously it means that the constructor is called repeatedly and that call fails repeatedly. This is not good programming style, find a way to check if the constructor call can succeed first.
UPDATE: 
Please also switch to a logging library like log4j, slf4j (only a wrapper) or at least something from java.util.logging - so you can direct the log output independently from the method of calling your program (nohup)

Comment: Thanks, @Kayaman. I'll try to implement your solution.

Comment: Thanks, @cyberbrain. I consider your suggestion and I'll try to implement it.